# How do I refer to a spcific datatable in IronPython in Spotfire?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I need to refer to a specific datatable in Spotfire in IronPython.

currently I'm seeing references to this but the datatable I need 'may' not be the one that is active.

```
Document.ActiveDataTableReference
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can refer to any table by name using this syntax:

```
Document.Data.Tables["mytable"]
```

Comment: couldn't find them with a search.  I'm going to start asking a bunch of Spotfire IronPython questions to start beefing up SO's coding base for Spotfire, so be on the look out.

Comment: yeah it's not a specific question, but buried in some other responses :) apologies if I sounded snarky; I'll edit that out. and bring on the questions!

Comment: oh not at all.  no worries.